# sql query select statement statistics

Tags: sql, select, statistics

I am looking for statistics on query execution, not of a specific application, but the average by world's usage, something very typical. Specifically I want the SELECT statement statistics, the WHERE statement, what would be the statistics for LIKE, IN(), = (exact match) ... What is the average amount of fields in a WHERE statement ?
Also, how many tables are joined on average in a typical SQL application? There must be some patterns in the usage of SQL query language and I am looking for specific numbers.

(it is for a project I am developing, an open source database engine)

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can modify the code of [mk-query-digest.html](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-digest.html) analysis tool. It's written in Perl.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for the statistics (numbers), not statistics generation tools.

Comment: Well, a statistics generating tool can generate statistics if you feed it properly.